# Ensuring a Spring Batch step is always run

Tags: spring-batch

We have the following Spring Batch configuration:

```
<batch:job id="job">
   <batch:step id="step1" next="step2">
      <batch:tasklet>
         <batch:chunk reader="reader" processor="processor"  writer="writer"
             commit-interval="10" />
      </batch:tasklet>
   </batch:step>

   <batch:step id="step2" >
      <batch:tasklet ref="tasklet" />
   </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

Works well, with one issue: if there are no items to be read by the item-reader, **step2** will never be called. For our use case,**step2** must always be called even if **step1** has no items to read. What is the best approach here?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

I presume you mean that the file is not found in step1.  If the file is found, but with no records, the step should complete normally and step2 should be executed by default.  If you want to turn off the check for the file, set the strict flag to false.

Comment: In step1, there is no file. The reader is actually a JdbcCursorItemReader, so it uses a sql SELECT. If no rows are returned, step2 is not called.

Comment: What is the exit status of step1?

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is from the log, in a case where no rows are returned: Job: [FlowJob: [name=myJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]

Comment: That is the exit status for the job.  I was asking about the step.

Comment: Is the strict flag set at the reader, job or the step level? And how do I do that using ReaderBuilder, JobBuilderFactory or StepBuilderFactory?